# make table header fixed but, need scroll in x and y direction

Tags: html, css

I want to make table header fixed but, need scroll in x and y direction.
please check this link for my code. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RaruRv/2kp6wfor/)

```css
.tableOuterDiv{
  overflow:auto;
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
th{
  width :100px;
  background-color:green;
}
body{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableOuterDiv">
<table  id=" ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>heading 1</th>
      <th>heading 2</th>
     <th>heading 3</th>
      <th>heading 4</th>
      <th>heading 5</th>
      <th>heading 6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
      <td>body data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to make the thead fixed and need scroll in x and y direction.

Comment: [check this](https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd)

Comment: where is your link ?

Comment: [check this also](https://codepen.io/sambible/pen/yOqKaN)

Comment: You need to include your link